# ASP.NET Core Background task with service container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

In an ASP.NET Core Web API project, I use `Task.Run` to trigger a long running operation.

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost("endpoint1")]
public ActionResult Endpoint1()
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        // create a new IoC container from scratch
        // do some long running operation using the services from the container
    });
    return Ok();
}
```

I would have a few question to it:

1. Will the running task not be disposed while it is running since
   there is no reference to it? Is it safe in this regard?
2. Inside the `Run` method I create a new IoC container containing services from scratch.
   Would there be a better alternative that would solve this issue?

Comment: _"// create a new IoC container from scratch'_ - this is rarely a good idea)

Comment: Check out the duplicate and follow the links. Use [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) + create scope per item (see [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task))